# Replacement of SimpleAttributeModifier in wicket 6.x or 7.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I came to know SimpleAttributeModifier is depricated in wicket 1.5,So i tried to write below code in new version of wicket

```
WebMarkupContainer expHidden = new WebMarkupContainer("exp");
           expHidden.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("value", CLAS.rsaUtil().getExponential()));
            add(expHidden);
```

So I changed it to,

```
WebMarkupContainer expHidden = new WebMarkupContainer("exp");

 expHidden.add(new AttributeModifier("value", CLAS.rsaUtil().getExponential()));
        add(expHidden);
```

It will work same as previous code?

Comment: Yes . it will work.You are going right path

Comment: Thanks, actually i can test my code after fixing all the issues only, That's y I have to be sure, Thanks for your support

Comment: Its all right . happy to help . You are welcome

Comment: If you don't mind, how can I write 
setRedirect(true); i came to know wicket will handle automatically,'but any replacement is there? like RenderPageRequestHandler.RedirectPolicy.ALWAYS_REDIRECT;

Comment: There is no redirect true .I believe you are looking for this `throw new RestartResponseException(MyPage.class, params);`?

Comment: I have code like this
 catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("**** Exception ***********");
    setRedirect(true);
    log.errorException(e);
    showErrorMsg(getLocalizer().getString("request.process.page.error", this));
   }

Comment: I believe something is missing in your code . It seems you are setting redirect to true but no idea where you are redirecting?

Comment: Feel free to add a new question

Comment: Ok i will post. i need to wait for 90 min no, so I couldn't.. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147892/discussion-between-s-p-roopesh-and-soorapadman).